# chmod: cannot access ‘x’: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, shebang

I was trying to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmqkncV6JIY. Basically I want to use shebang in my python code. I'm trying to run commands on AWS Linux instance. I got error while running

`chmod + x ​ file.py`

The error I got

`chmod: cannot access ‘x’: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between `+` and `x`:

```
chmod +x ​file.py
```